# C# Timer working

Tags: timer

I have some basic queries. I am working on C#.net.

1. Is timer event created on separate thread ?
2. I am creating a timer event every 100 miliseconds and calling a same function that is performing some task like DB access etc. What will be the result if process is not able to complete the function task within 100 ms and next timer event generated ?
3. what should i do to avoid such situation?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you talk about System.Timers.Timer, then yes.
2. The Timer event is called on another ThreadPool thread. Please see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.100).aspx
3. I would recommend to rethink your solution, and avoid using timers at all. You may use other synchonization mechanisms like semaphors, ... It would depend on your case.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple different timers in c# and some are created on a separate thread and some run on the same thread.

This document - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx is a very good overview of the 3 you'll most commonly see

- System.Windows.Forms.Timer
- System.Timers.Timer
- System.Threading.timer

from the article in question

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                  |System.Windows.Forms|System.Timers| System.Threading|
+----------------------------------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------+
|Timer event runs on what thread?  | UI thread          | UI or worker| Worker thread   |
|Instances are thread safe?        | No                 | Yes         | No              |
|Familiar/intuitive object model?  | Yes                | Yes         | No              |
|Requires Windows Forms?           | Yes                | No          | No              |
|Metronome-quality beat?           | No                 | Yes*        | Yes*            |
|Timer event supports state object?| No                 | No          | Yes             |
|Can schedule initial timer event? | No                 | No          | Yes             |
|Class supports inheritance?       | Yes                | Yes         | No              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
* Depending on the availability of system resources (for example, worker threads)
```

If you can get away with using the Windows.Forms timer you don't need to worry about the situation you describe.

See [http://blog.scosby.com/post/2009/01/04/Thread-synchronization-with-the-SystemTimersTimer-class-(part-one).aspx](http://blog.scosby.com/post/2009/01/04/Thread-synchronization-with-the-SystemTimersTimer-class-%28part-one%29.aspx) for example of how to prevent more than one thread calling your code when using System.Timers.Timers